# Mother married and got a Dutch passport before I was 18

Tags: passport, dutch-citizens

If my mother got married and got a Dutch passport before I was 18 years old, could I qualify for a Dutch passport now that I'm older?

Comment: How did she get this Dutch passport?  Was she naturalized?  When did this happen?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10899/do-i-qualify-for-a-dutch-passport?rq=1

Comment: In short, it seems unlikely, but there could be circumstances in which it would be possible,.  Without more details it's impossible to answer. I'm voting to close because of the lack of detail.

Comment: If this does get closed for "lack of detail", you can edit it to add the detail, and tick the box to say you have clarified the question.